# Редактировать определенную строку в файле?

Tags: php, файлы

Как можно редактировать определенную строчку в файле? Там записан допустим 0, я получаю ноль с помощью `$fil = @file($user); $count = $fil[5];`, теперь мне нужно удалить этот 0 и вместо него записать 1 в файл, т.е. увеличить значение на 1.

Comment: А как выглядит сома строка в файле ? Приводите больше и подробных данных

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, просто 0. Больше ничего нет. На других строчках другие данные, поэтому полностью чистить файл нельзя.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос добавив последнюю информацию.я правильно понял : у вас в файле лежат строки разделённые enter(\r\n),и одна строка из них это число 0 ?

Comment: Если там только одна строка и только одна цифра в этой строке вам будет достаточно функций file_get_contents() и file_put_contents()

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan, да, строк порядка 100, разделённые \n, и 6 строка это 0. Вот ее нужно увеличивать на единицу при каждом вызове функции.

Comment: @fens, нет, строк намного больше. Одна из них просто счётчик и он находится на 0. Его нужно увеличивать на единицу при каждом вызове функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуемся двумя замечательными функциями [**file**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) и [**file_put_contents**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)

Предположить у нас есть файл `test.txt` со следующими строками :

```
0
a
b
c
d
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php 
    function visitCounter()
    {
        $file = 'test.txt' ;
        $array = file( $file ); //файл в котором надо заменить строку, разбираем в массив построчно

        if($array)
        {
            //предполагаю по вашим ответам что число счетчика находится на
            //первой строке ,если же нет то укажите его номер в квадратных
            //скобках($array[n] ...) учитывая что отсчет идет от нуля
            $array[0] =((int)$array[0] + 1) . "\n"; // увеличиваем первый элемент массива(условно говоря первую строку файла) на единицу.
        }
        file_put_contents( $file, $array ); // записываем обратно в файл
    }

    visitCounter();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что вы знаете номер строки заранее.

**index.php**

```
<?
$lines = file('./filename.txt');//преобразуем файл в массив
$count = $lines[1];
$lines[8] = strval($count+1)."\n";//инкрементируем наш элемент массива и преобразуем его в строку
file_put_contents("./file.txt", $lines);//пишем строку в файл
$lines = file('./file.txt');
print_r($lines);
```

**filename.txt**

```
строка0
0
строка2
строка3
строка4
```

Comment: Ничего не происходит когда запускаю файл с пхп кодом .А когда вместо <? пишу <?php выскакивает следующая ошибка : Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\indx.php on line 4

Comment: @Sergey, Новые ошибки уровней E_WARNING и E_NOTICE были добавлены в php 7.1 при использовании некорректных строк с операторами, ожидающими числа (+ - * / ** % << >> | & ^) и их эквивалентами с присваиванием. Ошибка уровня E_NOTICE выдается, когда строка начинается с цифр, но далее содержит не цифровые символы, и ошибка уровня E_WARNING выдается тогда, когда строка вообще не содержит цифр. Так как ваша элемент массива с нулем на самом деле является строкой, где содержится 0 и перенос строки. Это всего лишь предупреждение, на работу скрипта оно не влияет.